# Karma-Jasmine: How to test ionicModal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

**THE SITUATION:**

In my Ionic app I am testing the correct opening of a modal.

I have made several attempts, but i am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

**THE FUNCTION:**

```
$scope.open_register_modal = function() 
{
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/project_register.html', {
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function(modal) { 
        $scope.modal_register = modal;
        $scope.modal_register.show();
    });
};
```

**THE TEST:**

```
describe('App tests', function() {

    beforeEach(module('my_app.controllers'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_)
    {
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new(); 

        $ionicModal = 
        {
            fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl'),
            then : function(modal){}  // <--- attempt
        }; 

         var controller = $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope, $ionicModal: $ionicModal });
    }));


    describe('Modal tests', function() 
    {
        it('should open register modal', function() 
        {
            $scope.open_register_modal();

            expect($ionicModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });

});
```

**ATTEMPTS:**

These are some of the attempts to initialize $ionicModal:

**1.**

```
    $ionicModal = 
    {
        fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl'),
        then : function(modal){} 
    };
```

**2.**

```
    $ionicModal = 
    {
        fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl'),
        then: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.then')
    };
```

**3.**

```
    $ionicModal = 
    {
        fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl'),
        then: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl.then')
    };
```

**4.**

```
    $ionicModal = jasmine.createSpyObj('$ionicModal', ['show', 'close','fromTemplateUrl']);
```

But they all give the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i pass the .then method inside the test?

How can i properly test ionicModal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about ionic, but I think your mistake is expecting that the method `then` is part of it. The code

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/project_register.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) { 
    $scope.modal_register = modal;
    $scope.modal_register.show();
});
```

can be refactor to:

```
var temp=$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl(
        'templates/project_register.html', 
        {scope: $scope});

temp.then(function(modal) { 
    $scope.modal_register = modal;
    $scope.modal_register.show();
});
```

so the method `then` is part of the object returned by the call to `fromTemplateUrl`

A solution could be something like:

```
function fakeTemplate() {
    return { then:function(){}}
}
 $ionicModal = {
        fromTemplateUrl: jasmine.createSpy('$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl').and.callFake(fakeTemplate)
    };
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Pablo! Now is working! I don't get any error and a variable inside modal_register() is properly tested that become true after calling the function. I still have to understand how to actually test the proper functioning of the modal (open, close) but now i resolve the main point of the question!